# Is this quadratic pointing up or down? How do I know?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, graphing-functions, quadratics

The equation is $-2x^2 + 4x + 30 = 0$. 
I simplified it to $-2(x^2 - 2x - 15)$.

To know if it points up, I need to look at $ax^2$, and if $a > 0$ it is up and if $a$ is $< 0$ it is down.

However, which version do I look at? In the original version, it would be pointing down. In the simplified version, it would be pointing up

Comment: This site uses [MathJax formatting of formulas](//math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(from a bot)*

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: The way I think about it is like this: if $x$ is really large, the $x^2$ term is a lot bigger than the $x$ term or the constant term. So if $a$ is negative, for large $x$, $ax^2$ is *really* negative. If $a$ is positive, then $ax^2$ is *really* positive. Factoring out the $-2$ obfuscates the matter. Leave the $-2$ together with the $x^2$ term as that is the correct way to judge the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to state the result you're trying to apply more clearly:

> The function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is pointing up when $a>0$ and is pointing down when $a<0$.

I write this out to emphasize that this requires $f$ to be written in standard form as $ax^2+bx+c$ - so you should look at that equation. That said, if you have something like $-2(x^2-2x-15)$, it's pretty easy to see that when you distribute out to get this in standard form, the coefficient of $x$ will be $-2$, so it points down, but it's still good to think about the intermediate step of distributing everything, even if you don't carry it out in full.

Comment: This answer is very misleading. There is not *one* result here, and one does not need to "think about the intermediate step of distributing everything." There are many results, and "standard form" has nothing to do with it. One could also think about the functional form $f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic One could adopt a view more agnostic to form, but I don't think it would be a very useful answer, given that the question here is fundamentally about having two forms and wishing to extract a piece of information usually found in a coefficient of a particular form - so the crux of the answer should be to identify the (or at least *a*) form where the coefficient has the desired meaning. In any case, the result I wrote seems to be the one the OP is appealing to and, more universally, is a reasonable way to characterize the direction a quadratic points in.

Comment: I disagree with your claim about usefulness. What matters here is not a particular functional form but the end behavior of the function (i.e., its behavior as $x\to\pm\infty$), and emphasizing "standard form," in particular, misses the point: a student needs to know that end behavior can be deduced from many forms. Cameron Williams's comment is closer to the point: the OP should think about what happens as $|x|$ gets big. That procedure will work in many settings, not just those that admit a typical normal form.

Comment: @symplectomorphic  Then why dont you add your own answer? I think the answer provided by Milo seems adequate for this user

Answer (score 0):

You must analyze the **function** $f(x)= -2x^2+4x+30$. You cannot set the function equal to $0$ unless you are trying to solve for the $x$ intercepts.

To determine the concavity of the function (whether it is up or down), you must look at the coefficient of the $x^2$ term. In either case, $-2x^2+4x+30$ or $-2(x^2 - 2x - 15)$, the coefficient is $-2$, indicating that the function is facing downwards, since $-2<0$.

Answer (score 0):

You started your post by talking about the equation The equation is $$-2x^2 + 4x + 30 = 0.$$ And you correctly noticed that $-2x^2 + 4x + 30 = -2(x^2 - 2x - 15)$, which means that this equation is equivalent to 
$$x^2 - 2x - 15=0.$$

If you are only interested in the roots, then it does not matter which of the two equations you take. The roost are the $x$-intercepts of the graph of $$f(x)=-2x^2 + 4x + 30.$$ But the $x$-intercepts of the graph of $$g(x)=x^2 - 2x - 15$$ are exactly the same.

The function $f(x)$ is a quadratic function which is [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function), the function $g(x)$ is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function). One of the graphs is directed downwards, the other on upwards. But the difference between the graphs of these two functions is only important if you also are interested in other properties of these functions. Not if you only need to find points for which $f(x)=0$. (Which is equivalent to $g(x)=0$.)